# May I omit the definite article here? Or else it'll be 'the The'

Tags: sentence-construction, definite-article, sentence-structure

The name of the popular daily is **The New York Times.** I'm talking about ***its*** reporter. May I omit the definite article from this sentence?

> I'm talking about Paul, *the* **The New York Times** reporter.

The first *the* is grammatically introduced as a modifier of the word *reporter* whereas the capital **The** is the part of the daily's name.

Is this right then?

> I'm talking about Paul, *the* New York Times reporter.

I **must** include *the (and not The)* in my sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this "the" is regularly omitted, and the capital "The" in the second sentence would be wrong (because "the" is modifying "reporter," not "New York Times").

Answer (score -2):

I'm talking about Paul, the New York Times reporter. is incorrect because "The New York Times" is itself the name of newspaper. So writing "I'm talking about Paul, The New York Times reporter" will be good enough for you :)